# Using 3D models in an 2D Game in libGDX

Tags: 2d, libgdx, 3d, rendering

In my libGDX 2D RPG-Game (like Zelda or something) I want to display some items as 3D-Objects. Since I'm using an OrthographicCamera like this:

```
this.gameWorldCam = new OrthographicCamera();
this.hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
gameWorldCameraViewport = new ExtendViewport(FRUSTUM_WIDTH, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT, gameWorldCam);
```

I don't know how to render 3D-Object on it. In my render loop I call this:

```
// 2D
spritebatch.begin();
...
spritebatch.end();

// ----------------------------------------------
// Just some hardcoded model creation for testing
// ----------------------------------------------
Model model;
ModelInstance instance;
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
model = modelBuilder.createBox(
  5f,
  5f,
  5f,
  new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
  Usage.Position | Usage.Normal
);
instance = new ModelInstance(model);
// ---------------------------------------------

// 3D
modelBatch.begin(gameWorldCam);
modelBatch.render(instance);
modelBatch.end();

// 2D
spritebatch.begin();
...
spritebatch.end();
```

What do I have to do, to get the proper result? Right now, nothing of the green 3D cube is visible.

Comment: It might be because of the place where the camera is and the place where that 3d object is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment, but it looks like it's a problem with the camera as the code looks fine. If the camera is inside the object it will not render properly. if your camera it's on the plane Z on the position 0 and your model it's also on that position your are not going to see it. Lower the z on the object or up the camera. Also the camera should have a far and a near values that will render the object even if you move the camera far away.

It also needs the material ambient set to more than > 0 to be visible or and environment added to the render that has it's own light.

In this last case you can add environments like this:

```
Environment environment = new Environment();
environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f)); //20% of minimum light for all objects on this environment
modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
```

Using environments you can also use an environment with point of ligh to give a dynamic shadow to the object (note, it will not cast a shadow on his own):

```
//cast a light from a point. If the object has this enviroment it will be affected by it.
environmentSun.add(new PointLight().set(1f, 1f, 1f, posX, posY, posZ, 1000));
```

Please note that in this last case the point of light should be outside of the model or it will not work for the model.